# Disabling Review and Photo Gallery from specific products - Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I'm looking for how to disable review field and photo gallery from some specific products.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

simple solutions is create two attributes from

> Stores -> Configuration -> Attributes -> Product

Create new attribute with **custom_review** and **custom_gallery** both with set  **Catalog Input Type for Store Owner** equals **Yes/No**.

Now Set Both of your attribute inside your **`attribute set`**.

You have seen Both attributes inside your each catalog product page.
For Those products, you are to show gallery and review set Yes from dropdown and for remaining products set No.

Now you can check condition before review and gallery code loaded,

ex, for review code,

```
<?php if($_product->getCustomReview()){
   //review code goes here
} ?>
```

same as gallery code,

```
<?php if($_product->getCustomGallery()){
       //galery code goes here
    } ?>
```

Run command

> php bin/magento indexer:reindex

Comment: Wow. Thanks so much... I'm almost there. Which files do I need to insert the condition?

Comment: I edited the following file:  app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/gallery.phtml and added on top to see: <?php
echo $_item->getCustomGallery();
if($_product->getCustomGallery()){
?> and to the very bottom <?php } ?> Nothing shows, even the " echo"

Answer (score 0):

In `Stores > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Product Reviews`, you can untick `Allow Guests to Write Reviews`. At least this will prevent guests from posting reviews, but it won't remove the field altogether.

If you want to do it programmatically, you could write a module that would add 2 new controls to the product's page in the admin panel: enable / disable reviews, and enable / disable photo gallery.

More specifically, for reviews...
write a plugin for `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description->getGroupChildNames`

Check if the control is on, then reviews should be displayed.

Regarding the photo gallery.. 
Do a rewrite for the template

```
module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/gallery.phtml
```

The file calls the gallery plugin. 
You can make it so that, depending on your setting, the required values for showing the gallery are set for options in the gallery plugin.